# duda ssl y www. en servidores apache

Tags: html

soy nuevo en este tema de la programacion web y tengo dos dudas que no pude resolver

respecto al www. que seria esto, parte del dns ?

en cuanto al certificado ssl, estuve viendo que hay varias paginas que los ofrecen gratuitos, mas que nada para practicar queria saber

la cosa es que tengo un servidor montado en xampp con los puertos del router abiertos, hasta aca todo bien, las personas pueden entrar sin problemas, pero no encontre forma de instalar un certificado ssl para acceder mediante https, ni tampoco puedo acceder usando wwww. (tengo un dns gratuito que me da noip.com)

si alguien es tan amable de resolverme esas dos dudas, muchas gracias

Comment: por convención `www` es el "nombre" del equipo que sirve páginas web, no es estrictamente necesario, técnicamente es un subdominio y se puede definir con un A, CNAME o ALIAS . noip.com seguramente ya te asignó un "subdomino". en principio certificados ssl sólo los puede pedir el "dueño" del dominio ( en este caso noip.com ) pero si noip te deja crear txt records podes usar letsencrypt para solicitar un certificado

Comment: Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema.